# discount and percentage question, how to solve this

Tags: contest-math

To attract more visitors, Zoo authority announces $20\%$ discount on every ticket which cost $\$25$. For this reason, sales of tickets increases by $28\%$. Find the $\%$ of increase in the number of visitors.

A $40\%$

B $50\%$

C $60\%$

D no change

How to solve this?

Comment: 1 price of ticket $20 but dont know how to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ is initial number of visitors, and $y$ is a number of visitors after discount. We have
$$25\cdot0.8y=25x\cdot 1.28,$$ so $$y/x=1.28/0.8=1.6$$ So, C is right answer.

Comment: great sir .this is good method

Answer (score 1):

Call $n$ the number of tickets told.

Before the discount, the profit would have been $25n$.

Now, the price per ticket is decreased to 20\$ (remove one fifth, which is 5\$). Let's call $m$ the number of visitors the zoo attracts now.

If the profit has increased by 28%, we must have $1.28(25n)=20m$. Hence,

$$m=\frac{1.28(25n)}{20}$$

Now you just need to find $$\frac{m-n}{n}$$ which gives $0.6$. So the answer is $C) 60\%$.

Comment: this method little bit complex but i am understand that how to solve .thank u

Answer (score 0):

change in sale price=discount+increase in visitor + (discount * increase in         vistor)/100

28=(-20)+V + {((-20)*V)/100}

V=60%